# Table width is shrinking when drag and drop ui-tree in Angular JS is used

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create drag and drop for a table using Angular JS ui tree.

Here is the table:

[image]

The drag and drop is working fine, but my table width is shrinking and height is incresing while dragging as shown:

[image]

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div style="width: 31%; float: left; margin-right: 12px;">

  <table data-ui-tree="treeOptions" id="tree-root" class="smallTable">
    <col width=10>
      <col width=30>
        <col width=100>
          <col width=20>
            <tr class="heading">
              <th colspan="4">Test</th>

            </tr>
            <tr class="columnsHeading">
              <th></th>
              <th>Col1</th>
              <th>Col2</th>
              <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="showNewtestRow()" style="color: #428bca; padding-left: 10px;"></span></th>
            </tr>
            <tbody ui-tree-nodes ng-model="tests">
              <tr ng-repeat="test in tests" ui-tree-node>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical" ui-tree-handle></span> </td>
                <td calss="smallTableColumn1" data-ng-hide="test.isEditable">{{test.testId}}</td>
                <td calss="smallTableColumn2" data-ng-hide="test.isEditable">{{test.testName}}</td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-click="showEdittestRow(test)" data-ng-hide="test.isEditable" style="color: rgb(66, 139, 202);"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-click="showtestConfirm(test)" data-ng-hide="test.isEditable"
                  style="color: rgb(66, 139, 202);"></span> <span data-ng-show="test.isEditable" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" ng-click="updatetest(test)" style="color: rgb(66, 139, 202);"></span> <span data-ng-show="test.isEditable" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"
                  ng-click="cancelEdittestRow(test)" style="color: red;"></span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shruthi, i see syntax error for the col width , it should be col width="10", quotes are missing . Hope this works for you :)

Comment: @Naga Sai A, I tried the same. But its not working. Still the same problem.

Comment: try adding CSS for table as table {layout:fixed}

Comment: I changed to width="10%" and its working fine now :) Thank you :)

Comment: Did my comment helped your question ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your expected result, add quotes to the col width

```
            <table data-ui-tree="treeOptions" id="tree-root" class="smallTable">
                <col width="10">
                <col width="30">
                <col width="100">
                <col width="20">
```